# Set post thumbnail size wordpress - percentage

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to generate all my uploaded images sizes by either

`set_post_thumbnail_size( $width, $height, $crop );`

or add custom size

```
add_image_size()
```

but the problem is: I dont want fixed width or height I want to set it to percentage like half 50%
something like this:

`set_post_thumbnail_size( 50%, 50%, $crop );
set_post_thumbnail_size( 50%, auto, $crop );`

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
if(has_post_thumbnail()) {                    
    $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(),'full' );
     echo '<img src="' . $image_src[0]  . '" width="100%"  />';
}
```

Comment: sorry maybe I didnt explain my self properly, I want to regenerate my images as I have very large images (1200*2400) which make my page very heavy. the way i am doing it now is by add_size_image('600', '1200'); or by setting the size of the thumbnails but instead of putting pixel value i was looking for a way to put percentage